# Why does sbt keep downloading my snapshot dependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management, ivy

I have an SBT project that depends on two snapshot dependencies. Every time I build it, it goes off to the remote repository to fetch the dependencies. This is true even if I set `offline := true`.

When I look at how it is trying to resolve the local dependencies, the build is saying it is looking in "local", i.e., `~/.ivy2/local/...` -- which is a nonexistent directory.

The jars are in `~/.ivy2/cache/...` and this is where SBT downloads them when it pulls the dependencies from the remote server.

I have searched my .sbt and .scala build files and the string "local" does not appear in them in connection with a repository or cache.

SBT is at version 0.13.11 building against scala 2.11.8.

Why is SBT doing this, and how can I get it to see the cached jars?

Comment: The ~/.ivy2/local directory is the default local Ivy repository to which you can publish using publish-local. (See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Detailed-Topics/Publishing.html .) So the issue is that SBT isn't looking at the local cache at all.

Comment: More discussion of this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395307/working-offline-with-sbt-and-snapshot-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent SBT from trying to download from official repositories you could simply create a file `project/offline-repositories`:

```
[repositories]
  mirror-central: file:////nexus/central
  mirror-maven-central-org: file:////nexus/maven-central-org
  ...
```

*(`/nexus/central` and `/nexus/maven-central-org` should contain a (partial) mirror of what you need offline)*

Then call `sbt` with the `sbt.repository.config` property configured:

```
-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true \
-Dsbt.repository.config=./project/offline-repositories
```

For Reference:

- http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html
- [How to prevent SBT from trying to download from official repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248726/how-to-prevent-sbt-from-trying-to-download-from-official-repositories)

**EDIT**

If you want to use your `~/.m2` cache:

```
[repositories]
  mirror-central: file:////home/XXXXX/.m2/repository
  mirror-maven-central-org: file:////home/XXXXX/.m2/repository
  ...
```

Comment: The problem was that it wasn't using the local ivy cache when the files were in the cache.  Your suggestion is a workaround, but it doesn't really address the issue I raised.

Comment: True, it is a workaround as I don't think it would be possible. Let's wait for more answers and if I am wrong I will remove this response.

Answer (score 0):

This apparently is because in my Ivy cache I had a file named ~/.ivy2/cache/com.xxx/xxx-utils/ivy-2.3.2-SNAPSHOT.xml.original , which the build was trying and failing to parse. I'm not sure where this file came from; conceivably it was put there manually ages ago.

Comment: I seem to have been mistaken about this. I created a local Ivy repository and the build passed. I then tried removing the local Ivy repository under ~/.ivy2/local and my build worked -- but then I tried building a different project using the same snapshot jar and the build failed. When I put the local Ivy repository back the second build passed.